# Two antecedents for $y\ne \min_{[a,b]}f(x),\max_{[a,b]}f(x)$ where $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ a continuous function such that $f(a)=f(b).$

Let $y\in f([a,b])$ such that $$y\ne \min_{[a,b]}f(x)\quad\mbox{and}\quad y\ne \max_{[a,b]}f(x).$$

I would like to prove that exist $c_1\ne c_2\in [a,b]$ such that $y=f(c_1)=f(c_2).$

If am not mistaken the fact that $f(a)=f(b)$ implies that there exist $a<c<b$ such that $f(c)>f(a)=f(b)$ or $f(c)<f(b)=f(a).$

Now we have $$\min_{[a,b]}f(x)\le f(a)=f(b)<f(c)\le \max_{[a,b]}f(x)$$ or $$\min_{[a,b]}f(x)\le f(c)<f(a)=f(b)\le \max_{[a,b]}f(x).$$

So we have lot of cases for $y.$ Not sure what I have to do.

I now that I must use somewhere the intermediate value theorem but what struggle me is that $y$ is fixed at the beginning.

Now geometrically I cannot think of anything other than the graph always has a symmetry so that the property hold for $y.$

How can I "continue"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote by $m$ the minimum and by $M$ the maximum of $f$.

Suppose that there exists $y_0\in[m,M]$ having only one antecedent $x_0$ in $[a,b]$.

Since $f(a)=f(b)$, we must have $a<x_0<b$.

The continuous map $x\mapsto f(x)-f(x_0)$ doesn't vanish neither on $[a,x_0)$ nor on $(x_0,b]$, hence has constant sign on each of theses intervals.

Those signs cannot be the same because $f(x_0)$ would belong to $\{m,M\}$.

So one of the two following cases holds :

1) $\forall x\in[a,x_0),\,f(x)<f(x_0)$ and $\forall x\in(x_0,b],\,f(x)>f(x_0)$

2) $\forall x\in[a,x_0),\,f(x)>f(x_0)$ and $\forall x\in(x_0,b],\,f(x)<f(x_0)$

But in both cases, we see that $f(a)\neq f(b)$ : a contradiction !